# Win7 Enterprise drivers for HP workstations/laptops

Tags: windows-7, drivers

When I install a default image of Windows 7 Enterprise on any HP workstation or laptop some of the drivers including Ethernet Controller do not load. I know I can install the drivers for that particular HP then use sysprep/imgx or SCCM Task squence to capture image.

However there must be a better via APK or OPK to make sure the main drivers like Ethernet and USB are installed no matter the HP workstation or laptop version?

I'm a Linux guy so I'm use to universal repositories but I know Windows OS does not have any.

Comment: [Most use Sysprep for this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preparing-an-image-using-sysprep-and-imagex.aspx)

Comment: Ya that's what I thought. Just thought there was a more universal way for all HP using windows 7 enterprise.  Thanks

Comment: HP may have software for doing this, not sure.